# Android AutoCompleteSearch

Tags: android

I am having a problem. I have an activity with a FragmentPagerAdapter and there i have 4 fragments which are displayed whenever i press the name in the action bar. The problem is that in one of the fragments i have implemented a map using Google Maps Api and also i have AutoCompleteSearch. The problem is that whenever i press AutoCompleteSearch to start writing it calls the onResume() on the Activity and then the input disappear. What can i do in order to be able to write something without calling onResume() ? The activity doesn't have anything to display...only the action bar with the name of the fragments from which to chose to display.

Solved: The problem was that even if i had a google map key i had to activate places api in google console(google maps api worked just fine).

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }

    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps, container, false);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete);


        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });


    } catch (InflateException e) {
        /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
    }
    return view;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a conditional return statement to the onResume so that it will be called exactly once:

```
if (alreadyResumed) {
return;
}
alreadyResumed = true;
```

This clearly will prevent calling it second time.

Comment: in the onResume() in the Activity?

Comment: @OtnielMercea in global variable

Comment: doesn't work...if i do that when the mainactivity(which will add the action bar and those 4 fragments) load it will crash with the following message:did not call through to super.onResume()